# Given a point outside of an arc, how can one find the point on the arc which extends to that point?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a point outside of an arc, how can one find the point on the arc which extends to that point?

For example, the radius of the circle (**R**) is 10cm, it's center point is [0,0].
The origin (**o**) of the line (**8**) is at  [-3, 10]
How can we find the point (**p**) (p8) were the tangent at that point continues to the origin of the line?

A brute force solution would not be acceptable.

[image: Extensions of arc]

Comment: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~m124/source/supps/circleTangents.pdf

Comment: @doggie_breath thanks, very useful, also got some answers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541795/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext/3541928#3541928 When I get some working code I'll post it here if no one else already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let point coordinates are `px, py`, and circle center is at `(0,0)` (if not - subtract center `cx, cy` from all coordinates to simplify equations, add them back at the end).

You can write two equations for unknown `x,y`. Circle equation and perpendicularity one - tangent is perpendicular to radius-vector, their dot product is zero.

```
(x - px) * x + (y - py) * y = 0
x^2 + y^2 = r^2

x^2 - px * x + y^2 - py * y = 0
r^2 - px * x = py * y
y = (r^2 - px * x) / py
y^2  = r^4 / py ^2 - x * 2 * r^2 * px / py^2 + x^2 * px^2 / py^2    

x^2 * (1 + px^2 / py^2) - x * 2 * r^2 * px / py^2 +  (r^4 / py^2 - r^2) = 0
x^2 * (py^2 + px^2) - x * 2 * r^2 * px  +  (r^4 - r^2 * py^2) = 0
```

Solve the last quadratic equation for `x`, then calculate `y`.

[image]

Delphi function for reference  (note: py=0 case is treated separately)

```
function GetTangentPts(px, py, r: Double): TArray<Double>;
var
  px2, py2, pxpy, r2, Dis, x, y: Double;
begin
  px2 := px * px;
  py2 := py * py;
  r2 := r * r;
  pxpy := px2 + py2;
  Dis := pxpy - r2;
  if Dis < 0 then    //point is inside
    Exit(nil)
  else if Dis = 0 then begin    //point is at circumference
    SetLength(Result, 2);
    if py = 0 then begin
      x := px;
      y := 0;
    end else begin
      x := px * r2 / pxpy;
      y := (r2 - px * x) / py;
    end;
    Result[0] := x;
    Result[1] := y;
  end else begin       //general case, two tangents
    SetLength(Result, 4);
    if py = 0 then begin
       y := - r * Sqrt(Dis) / px;
       x := px / Abs(px) * r * Sqrt(1 - Dis/px2);
       Result[0] := x;
       Result[1] := y;
       y := r * Sqrt(Dis) / px;
       Result[2] := x;
       Result[3] := y;
    end else begin
      x := (px * r2 - r * Sqrt(py2 * Dis)) / pxpy;
      y := (r2 - px * x) / py;
      Result[0] := x;
      Result[1] := y;
      x := (px * r2 + r * Sqrt(py2 * Dis)) / pxpy;
      y := (r2 - px * x) / py;
      Result[2] := x;
      Result[3] := y;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

some results:

```
10.00 10.00 10.00 //two perpendicular tangents
 0.00
10.00
10.00
 0.00

-10.00 10.00 10.00
-10.00
 0.00
 0.00
10.00

 1.00  1.00 10.00
 //inside

 0.00 10.00 10.00 //horizontal tangent
 0.00
10.00

10.00  0.00 10.00 //vertical tangent
10.00
 0.00

-14.14  0.00 10.00  //two tangents from OX-axis
-7.07
 7.07
-7.07
-7.07
```

Comment: I'll take a better look at this next week. In the screenshot you show the formula for the x values, I don't understand what's with Y. You have `y = (r^2 - px * x) / py` but shouldn't there be 2 Y values like there are 2 X values?

Comment: Yes, we need to calculate Y for both possible X

Comment: I implemented as follows but the result was way off can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `function tp(px, py, r) {
var x1, x2, y1, y2, pxSq, pySq, rSq, pyQu, alfa, delta, divider;
  pxSq = px * px;
  pySq = py * py;
  pyQu = pySq * pySq;
  rSq = r * r;
  alfa = 2 * px * pySq * r;
  delta =
    2 *
    r *
    Math.sqrt(pxSq * pyQu * rSq + pxSq * pySq - rSq * pxSq + pyQu - rSq * pySq);
  divider = 1 / (2 * (pxSq + pySq));
  x1 = (alfa + delta) * divider;
  x2 = (alfa - delta) * divider;
  y1 = (rSq - px * x1) / py;
  y2 = (rSq - px * x2) / py;
  return {
    point1: [x1, y1],
    point2: [x2, y2]
  };
}

tp(-30, 100, 100);`

Comment: Sorry, my fault - missed py^2 divider in the 6-th line. Corrected,

Comment: Ok, great, the Delphi function was **really** useful, I've ported it to js and added it to my answer. I've marked your's as correct as you deserve all the credit.

Comment: Found 2 bugs. (1) If pxpy < r2 then the point is inside the circle and there's no tangent. That is very easy to check for, see my edited snippet. (2) If py is 0 then no y position is calculated. In the second code, it is.
Example figures centerX & centerY 0, radius 10, px 20 (The point is outside the circle) py 0.
See my edited snippet to deal with a division of 0.
Any ideas of sorting out bug (2)?

Comment: Well I guess one can temporarily swap pX and pY

Comment: Does seem a bit messy

Comment: (1) is treated in code (2) - I emphasized this before the code, but was too lazy to implement :-). Added new code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I edited my snippet too, I'll compare. I missed the emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG the circle is centered at the origin. We express that a point on the circle, let `(u, v)`, forms a right angle with the lines to the center and to the target point `(x, y)`:

```
u (x - u) + v (y - v) = 0
```

or

```
u x + v y = r².
```

We rewrite and square to obtain

```
(r² - u²) y² = (r² - u x)²,
```

a quadratic equation in  `u`. From this, `v` = `√(r² - u²)` follows and you have the tangency point.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
**This first preferred method is a js version very much based on the method of @MBo** Fixes a couple of bugs there.

```js
function tangentLines(centerX, centerY, radius, pX, pY) {
  var horizontalAdjustment, verticalAdjustment, pX_Squared, pY_Squared,
    pXY_Squared, radiusSquared, delta, x, y, result, onSameY, temp

  // Center the circle at [0,0] to simplify things
  onSameY = pY === centerY
  horizontalAdjustment = centerX
  verticalAdjustment = centerY
  pX -= horizontalAdjustment
  pY -= verticalAdjustment
  centerX = centerY = 0
  // If pY is on the same vertical as centerY then temporarily swap pX and pY
  // to avoid bug caused by division of 0
  if(onSameY){
    temp = pY
    pY = pX
    pX = temp
  }

  pX_Squared = pX * pX
  pY_Squared = pY * pY
  radiusSquared = radius * radius
  pXY_Squared = pX_Squared + pY_Squared
  delta = pY_Squared * (pXY_Squared - radiusSquared)

  // Point is inside i.e. no tangent
  if (delta < 0 || pXY_Squared < radiusSquared) {
    return false
  }

  // Point is on circumference only one tangent point
  if (delta === 0) {
    x = (pX * radiusSquared)
    if (pXY_Squared) { x /= pXY_Squared }

    y = (radiusSquared - pX * x)
    if (pY) { y /= pY }
    x += horizontalAdjustment
    y += verticalAdjustment
    return onSameY ? [y,x] : [x, y]
  }

  // Regular case point is outside of tangent there are 2 tangent points
  x = (pX * radiusSquared - radius * Math.sqrt(delta))
  if (pXY_Squared) { x /= pXY_Squared }
  y = (radiusSquared - pX * x)
  if (pY) { y /= pY }
  x += horizontalAdjustment
  y += verticalAdjustment
  result = [
    onSameY ? [y, x] : [x, y],
    []
  ]
  x = (pX * radiusSquared + radius * Math.sqrt(delta))
  if (pXY_Squared) { x /= pXY_Squared }
  y = (radiusSquared - pX * x)
  if (pY) { y /= pY }
  x += horizontalAdjustment
  y += verticalAdjustment
  result[1] = onSameY ? [y, x] : [x, y]
  return result
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div>
          <div>
            centerX: <input v-model="centerX" @input="intersectionPoints">
            centerY:  <input v-model="centerY" @input="intersectionPoints">
            <div>radius: <input v-model="radius" @input="intersectionPoints"></div>
          </div>
          <div>
            pointX: <input v-model="pointX" @input="intersectionPoints">
            pointY: <input v-model="pointY" @input="intersectionPoints">
          </div>
          <div v-if=result>
          <div>Insect points: {{result}}</div>
          </div>
          <div v-if=!result>No intersections :-(</div>
        </div>
            `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      centerX: 200,
      centerY: 200,
      radius: 100,
      pointX: 160,
      pointY: 100,
      result: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    intersectionPoints() {
      this.result = tangentLines(
        +this.centerX,
        +this.centerY,
        +this.radius,
        +this.pointX,
        +this.pointY
      );
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.intersectionPoints();
  }
});

// Without Vue just use something like
// tangentLines(200, 200, 100, 160, 100);
```

```css
div {
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here's the original code I came up with.

Based on @Aretino answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541795/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext/3541928#3541928

1. Make a circle with a radius half the distance between `o` and `p`, originate it at the midpoint of the line `op`.
2. Calculate the intersection point of the original circle and the newly made circle.

[image: Intersection point]

```js
// Function to find tangent intersection points to a point outside of the circle
// Credits
// https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541795/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext/3541928#3541928
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156373/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext
/**
 *
 *
 * @param {number} centerX1 Center of circle 1 X
 * @param {number} centerY1 Center of circle 1 Y
 * @param {number} radius1 Radius of circle 1
 * @param {number} centerX2 Center of circle 2 X
 * @param {number} centerY2 Center of circle 2 Y
 * @param {number} radius2 Radius of circle 2
 * @returns {object | boolean} The to intersect points { point1: [x1, y1], point2: [x2, y2] } or false
 * @credit Math based on https://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_intersection_calcu.html
 */
var circleIntersections = function(
  centerX1,
  centerY1,
  radius1,
  centerX2,
  centerY2,
  radius2
) {
  var a, b, c, A, B, C, delta, x1, x2, y1, y2;

  a = -(centerY1 - centerY2) / (centerX1 - centerX2);
  b = 2 * (centerX1 - centerX2);
  c =
    (-radius1 * radius1 +
      radius2 * radius2 +
      centerX1 * centerX1 -
      centerX2 * centerX2 +
      centerY1 * centerY1 -
      centerY2 * centerY2) /
    b;
  A = a * a + 1;
  B = 2 * a * c - 2 * centerX1 * a - 2 * centerY1;
  C =
    c * c +
    centerX1 * centerX1 -
    2 * centerX1 * c +
    centerY1 * centerY1 -
    radius1 * radius1;
  delta = B * B - 4 * A * C;
  if (delta < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  y1 = (-B + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);
  x1 = a * y1 + c;
  y2 = (-B - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);
  x2 = a * y2 + c;

  return {
    point1: [x1, y1],
    point2: [x2, y2]
  };
};

/**
 *
 *
 * @param {number} centerX Center of circle X
 * @param {number} centerY Center of circle Y
 * @param {number} radius Radius of circle
 * @param {number} pointX Point to tangent to X
 * @param {number} pointY Point to tangent to Y
 * @returns {object | boolean} The to intersect points { point1: [x1, y1], point2: [x2, y2] } or false
 */
var tangentLines = function(centerX, centerY, radius, pointX, pointY) {
  var centerX2, centerY2, radius2, dX, dY;
  centerX2 = centerX - (centerX - pointX) / 2;
  centerY2 = centerY - (centerY - pointY) / 2;
  dX = centerX2 - centerX;
  dY = centerY2 - centerY;
  radius2 = Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);

  return circleIntersections(
    centerX,
    centerY,
    radius,
    centerX2,
    centerY2,
    radius2
  );
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div>
          <div>
            centerX: <input v-model="centerX" @input="intersectionPoints">
            centerY:  <input v-model="centerY" @input="intersectionPoints">
            <div>radius: <input v-model="radius" @input="intersectionPoints"></div>
          </div>
          <div>
            pointX: <input v-model="pointX" @input="intersectionPoints">
            pointY: <input v-model="pointY" @input="intersectionPoints">
          </div>
          <div v-if=result>
          <div>point1: {{result.point1}}</div>
          <div>point2: {{result.point2}}</div>
          </div>
          <div v-if=!result>No intersections :-(</div>
        </div>
            `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      centerX: 200,
      centerY: 200,
      radius: 100,
      pointX: 160,
      pointY: 100,
      result: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    intersectionPoints() {
      this.result = tangentLines(
        this.centerX,
        this.centerY,
        this.radius,
        this.pointX,
        this.pointY
      );
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.intersectionPoints();
  }
});

// Without Vue just use something like
// tangentLines(200, 200, 100, 160, 100);
```

```css
div {
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id=app></div>
```